# Correctly calculate the color opacity offset to change the background color when scrolling to prev/next image in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I apologize if the title is ambiguous but currently, I have a `UICollectionView` of images. I recently discovered a way to find the dominant colors of a `UIImage` using [DominantColor](https://github.com/indragiek/DominantColor). With this, I'm trying to change the `UICollectionView`'s background color as the user scrolls from one `UIImage` cell to the next, i.e. the background color will slowly fade from imageX's dominant color to imageX+1's dominant color.

However, I've spent days on this and am having a very difficult time in changing the background color opacity of the `UICollectionView` as the cell begins to scroll to the next/prev image.

My UI:

[image]

Background code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: imageView.frame.size.height)

    let subView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)

    subView.image = imagesArray[indexPath.row].theImage

    subView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

    cell.addSubview(subView)

    return cell
}

// The colorsArray will contain a dominant color for each image in the CollectionView
func dominantColorOfImages()
{
    for index in 0..<imagesArray.count
    {
        if let image = imagesArray[index].theImage
        {
            let colors: [UIColor] = image.dominantColors()

            colorsArray[index] = colors[index]
        }
    }

    // Default dominant background color for first image in CollectionView
    imagesCollectionView.backgroundColor = colorsArray[0]

    imagesCollectionView.reloadData()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    let pageWidth: CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.size.width

    let currentPage: Int = Int( floor( (scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)

    currentImagePage = currentPage
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    let pageWidth: CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.size.width
    let currentPage: Int = Int( floor( (scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1)

    // Horizontal
    let maximumHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width
    let currentHorizontalOffset: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x


    // This is the offset of how far the right side edge of the current image has pass the end of the left screen (i.e. when the user scrolls the image from the right to the left to get to the next image)
    let pageOffset: CGFloat = ( (pageWidth * CGFloat(currentImagePage) ) + (pageWidth / 2) ) / maximumHorizontalOffset

    if percentageHorizontalOffset < pageOffset
    {

        imagesCollectionView.backgroundColor = fadeFromColorToColor(fromColor: colorsArray[currentImagePage], toColor: colorsArray[currentImagePage + 1], withPercentage: percentageHorizontalOffset * CGFloat(colorsArray.count - 1 ) )

    }
    else
    {

        imagesCollectionView.backgroundColor = fadeFromColorToColor(fromColor: colorsArray[currentImagePage], toColor: colorsArray[currentImagePage + 1], withPercentage: (percentageHorizontalOffset - pageOffset) * CGFloat(colorsArray.count - 1) ))

    }
}

func fadeFromColorToColor(fromColor: UIColor, toColor: UIColor, withPercentage: CGFloat) -> UIColor
{
    var fromRed: CGFloat = 0.0
    var fromGreen: CGFloat = 0.0
    var fromBlue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var fromAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

    // Get the RGBA values from the colours
    fromColor.getRed(&fromRed, green: &fromGreen, blue: &fromBlue, alpha: &fromAlpha)

    var toRed: CGFloat = 0.0
    var toGreen: CGFloat = 0.0
    var toBlue: CGFloat = 0.0
    var toAlpha: CGFloat = 0.0

    toColor.getRed(&toRed, green: &toGreen, blue: &toBlue, alpha: &toAlpha)

    // Calculate the actual RGBA values of the fade colour
    let red = (toRed - fromRed) * withPercentage + fromRed;
    let green = (toGreen - fromGreen) * withPercentage + fromGreen;
    let blue = (toBlue - fromBlue) * withPercentage + fromBlue;
    let alpha = (toAlpha - fromAlpha) * withPercentage + fromAlpha;

    // Return the fade colour
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
}
```

This is following the same answer as provided here: [Changing between colors based on UIScrollView's contentOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261089/2373410), except `pageOffset` is hard-coded to be 0.5 since that question deals with 2 static pages while I'm dealing with `colorsArray.count - 1` pages, so I had to re-calculate the `pageOffset` differently.

The issue that I'm having is within `withPercentage` in `scrollViewDidScroll`.

The color fades fine as I start scrolling from Image1->Image2. But then right as soon Image2 stops, the background color jumps immediately to the color that is suppose to be in Image3 and enters the `else` statement.

To show example, here's the color opacity from image1->image2 output running on an iPhone 7 simulator:

```
scrollView.contentSize.width =1125.0
scrollView.frame.size.width =375.0
maximumHorizontalOffset =750.0
currentHorizontalOffset =110.5
pageOffset = 0.5
currentImagePage = 0
percentageHorizontalOffset = 0.147333333333333
IN IF
withPercentage in IF = 0.294666666666667

...

scrollView.contentSize.width =1125.0
scrollView.frame.size.width =375.0
maximumHorizontalOffset =750.0
currentHorizontalOffset =269.0
pageOffset = 0.5
currentImagePage = 0
percentageHorizontalOffset = 0.358666666666667
IN IF
withPercentage in IF = 0.717333333333333

...

scrollView.contentSize.width =1125.0
scrollView.frame.size.width =375.0
maximumHorizontalOffset =750.0
currentHorizontalOffset =374.5
pageOffset = 0.5
currentImagePage = 0
percentageHorizontalOffset = 0.499333333333333
IN IF
withPercentage in IF = 0.998666666666667

scrollView.contentSize.width =1125.0
scrollView.frame.size.width =375.0
maximumHorizontalOffset =750.0
currentHorizontalOffset =375.0
pageOffset = 0.5
currentImagePage = 0
percentageHorizontalOffset = 0.5
IN ELSE
withPercentage in ELSE  = 0.0
```

This is where I know my calculations are off, but I'm racking my brain on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code ready to be pasted into a playground. Open an assistant editor to play with the collection view. Is that what you are looking for?

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension UIColor {
    func components() -> (r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a: CGFloat) {
        var r: CGFloat = 0.0
        var g: CGFloat = 0.0
        var b: CGFloat = 0.0
        var a: CGFloat = 0.0
        getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
        return (r, g, b, a)
    }
}

class Controller: UICollectionViewController {

    // some test data instead of images:
    let pages = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)]

    // these should be your significant colors from the images:
    let colorsArray = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098054, green: 0.8392156959, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9098039269, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.6431372762, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627477, green: 0.6588235497, blue: 0.5450980663, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.721568644, green: 0.8862745166, blue: 0.5921568871, alpha: 1)]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = pages[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let currentHorizontalOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset.x + collectionView!.contentInset.left
        let pageWidth = scrollView.bounds.size.width
        let page = Int(max(0, floor(currentHorizontalOffset / pageWidth)))

        // Don't change the background color when scrolling past the last page:
        guard page < pages.count - 1 else {
            return
        }

        let partialPageVisibleWidth = currentHorizontalOffset - CGFloat(page) * pageWidth
        let ratio = max(0, partialPageVisibleWidth / pageWidth)

        let leftColor = colorsArray[page]
        let rightColor = colorsArray[page + 1]

        scrollView.backgroundColor = blend(leftColor, rightColor, ratio: ratio)
    }

    /**
    Blends two colors by the given ratio

    - returns: `lhs` if t == 0; `rhs` if t == 1; otherwise a blend of `lhs` and `rhs` by using a linear interpolation function
    */
    func blend(_ lhs: UIColor, _ rhs: UIColor, ratio t: CGFloat) -> UIColor
    {
        let (r1, g1, b1, a1) = lhs.components()
        let (r2, g2, b2, a2) = rhs.components()

        // Interpolation function:
        func f(_ from: CGFloat, _ to: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            return from * (1 - t) + to * t
        }

        // create a new color by interpolating two colors:
        return UIColor(
            red:   f(r1, r2),
            green: f(g1, g2),
            blue:  f(b1, b2),
            alpha: f(a2, a2)
        )
    }
}



// Test code:

let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: 400)
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 40

let controller = Controller(collectionViewLayout: layout)
controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller.view
```

Comment: currently my collection view has infinite scroll, i.e. you can go scroll from the 1st page -> last page and last page -> 1st page....how can you handle that case?

Comment: Maybe you can adapt the ideas presented in this WWDC video showing how to implement infinite scrolling for scroll views: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/104/

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to accurately read your code examples, as some vars/identifiers are not defined within the example text, e.g. percentageHorizontalOffset

What if you change the row in the else clause of the scrollViewDidScroll func to:

```
    imagesCollectionView.backgroundColor = fadeFromColorToColor(fromColor: colorsArray[currentImagePage], toColor: colorsArray[currentImagePage], withPercentage: (percentageHorizontalOffset - pageOffset) * CGFloat(colorsArray.count - 1) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `fadeFromColorToColor` if the percent is negative then swap `toColor` and `fromColor` and turn `percent` positive.